# Accessing _MobileAddress and _MobileSubscription Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

In trying to develop a process to deal with MobileConnect Contacts, I have come to understand that the old SMS DE `_SubscriberSMS` has been deprecated and that the new DEs that will contain this information are: `_MobileAddress` and `_MobileSubscription`. I presume that these DEs contain information about the Contact (with a primary key of mobile number or `SubscriberId`) and the contacts' subscriptions, respectively.

The information that was given to me (by ET) about `_MobileAddress` was that it contained the following fields:

```
City  
ContactID  
CountryCode  
CreatedBy  
CreatedDate  
FirstName  
LastName  
MobileNumber  
ModifiedBy  
ModifiedDate  
State  
Status  
ZipCode
```

However, when I try to set up a query like `SELECT MobileNumber FROM _MobileAddress`, I am told that that field does not exist. If I modify the DE to something like `_MobileAddressX` it tells me that DE doesn't exist, so presumably `_MobileAddress` exists and has an unknown set of fields.

Can anyone tell me how to get more information about `_MobileAddress` and `_MobileSubscription`?

What fields do they have?

Can I access it via API or only through Queries?

Since MobileConnect does not seem to support a series of functions for maintaining Mobile Contacts, it would be infinitely useful to be able to access those contacts and their subscriptions at the data level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the field names are correct (though not a complete list). They contain an underscore before each of them in the Data Extension. This makes things difficult when pulling the fields out using SELECT * because fields in [user created] Data Extensions cannot have a leading underscore.

So if you want to pull all the records from _MobileAddress you will need the following query:

```
SELECT _CarrierID AS CarrierID,
_Channel AS Channel,
_City AS City,
_ContactID AS ContactID,
_CountryCode AS CountryCode,
_CreatedBy AS CreatedBy,
_CreatedDate AS CreatedDate,
_FirstName AS FirstName,
_IsHonorDST AS IsHonorDST,
_LastName AS LastName,
_MobileNumber AS MobileNumber,
_ModifiedBy AS ModifiedBy,
_ModifiedDate AS ModifiedDate,
_Priority AS Priority,
_Source AS Source,
_SourceObjectID AS SourceObjectID,
_State AS State,
_Status AS Status,
_UTCOffset AS UTCOffset,
_ZipCode AS ZipCode
FROM _MobileAddress
```

And all the records from _MobileSubscription can be pulled with the following query:

```
SELECT 
_CreatedBy AS CreatedBy,
_OptOutMethodID AS OptOutMethodID,
_MobileNumber AS MobileNumber,
_OptInDate AS OptInDate,
_Source AS Source,
_OptOutStatusID AS OptOutStatusID,
_OptOutDate AS OptOutDate,
_ModifiedBy AS ModifiedBy,
_SourceObjectId AS SourceObjectId,
_SubscriptionDefinitionID AS SubscriptionDefinitionID,
_CreatedDate AS CreatedDate,
_OptInStatusID AS OptInStatusID,
_OptInMethodID AS OptInMethodID,
_ModifiedDate AS ModifiedDate
FROM _MobileSubscription
```

Comment: By any chance do you know what each value of the IDs mean e.g. OptInStatusID o OptInMethodID ? the results are returning a numberic value, but I'd like to know what the actual value meaning/name is. Cheers

Comment: @Macca
 _MobileAddress._Status 
1 = active
-1 = unspecified
2 = bounced
3 = held
4 = unsubscribed

 _MobileSubscription._OptOutStatusID 
0 = opted in
1 = opted out

 _MobileSubscription._OptInStatusID 
0 = opted out
1 = Opt In Pending
2 = opted in

Comment: Do you know if this view can provide ContactKey?

Comment: Additionally, if you have created your own custom Mobile Demographics attributes in Contact Builder, you can simply include their attribute names without an underscore prefix.

Answer (score 7):

In case you're wondering about the data types and such:

**_MobileAddress**

```
| Field Name      | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-              | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _ContactID      | Text               | Y              |              |
| _MobileNumber   | Text(15)           | Y              |              |
| _Status         | Text               | N              |              |
| _Source         | Text               | N              |              |
| _SourceObjectId | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _Priority       | Text               | N              | 1            |
| _Channel        | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _CarrierID      | Text               | Y              | 0            |
| _CountryCode    | Text(2)            | Y              |              |
| _CreatedDate    | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy      | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate   | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy     | Text               | N              |              |
| _City           | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _State          | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _ZipCode        | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _FirstName      | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _LastName       | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _UTCOffset      | Decimal(4,2)       | N              | 0            |
| _IsHonorDST     | Boolean            | N              | false        |
```

**_MobileSubscription**

```
| Field Name                | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-                        | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _SubscriptionDefinitionID | Text(200)          | Y              |              |
| _MobileNumber             | Text(15)           | Y              |              |
| _OptOutStatusID           | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutMethodID           | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutDate               | Date               | N              |              |
| _OptInStatusID            | Text               | Y              |              |
| _OptInMethodID            | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptInDate                | Date               | N              |              |
| _Source                   | Text               | N              |              |
| _CreatedDate              | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy                | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate             | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy               | Text               | N              |              |
```

I did an SOAP API retrieve on the `DataExtensionField` Object to get this info.