# MarketingCloud Data Extension to MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is there a way I can import mobile numbers from my DataExtension into my mobileConnect list?

Currently, first I have to filter my data then I need to export that file and then I modify the file and upload again in mobile connect.

I looking to fetch the data directly from my email DataExtension. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using **Import Mobile Contacts**: [MobileConnect with Automation Studio](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/creating_a_new_message_in_mobileconnect/prerequisites_for_using_mobileconnect_across_marketing_cloud/use_mobileconnect_with_automation_studio/). You can also process it manually using an [Import Definition](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/imports/create_a_new_import_definition/) in Contact Builder.
I currently have this working in a daily (scheduled) Automation, and it works well. 
Just be aware that "Importing" customers into the Mobile Connect "list" constitutes a "subscription", and will re-opt-in customers who may have unsubscribed from your SMS service.

Comment: How do you manage the fact that potentially opt-out contacts may become re-opt-in?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - Depending on your usage & data structure, you could use a Data Extension to hold subscription status (and use a Query Activity to check against it), or you could use the native _MobileAddress table (see: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions)