# MobileConnect - Unsubscribes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

For "All Subscribers" in a business unit we have an unsubscribe setting while creating and configuring business units to control the unsubscribes for Emails

[image: screenshot attached]

I have a question around something similar for MobileConnect, where we have a requirement to control the unsubscribes on a Business Unit level for contacts.

In this scenario, we have a long code defined at the Parent BU level, and what we want is a contact that unsubscribes by sending a STOP keyword via SMS, that subscriber should only be unsubscribed from the business unit they received the SMS from (not the parent business unit)

Can you please confirm if this settings applies to mobile contacts or there is a seperate setting for this and where is it located?

Answer (score 3):

@Nikhil Jaitly Typcially, the STOP keyword applies to the long code or short code sent from, so if you have a single instance set up or MobileConnect where your long code is shared across BUs, the STOP will suppress the contact across all sends from that long code, irrespective of BU.

Comment: Are there any DEs in MobileConnect where ClientID(Business Unit) information is saved, if we want to make use of them for any custom solution ?

Comment: What type of data are you looking for?

Comment: Any field which gives information around the Business Unit the Contact who unsubscribed, belonged to.

Comment: You can inspect the _MobileSubscription Data View that I think would be specific to the Business Unit in which it resides https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions. Alternatively, you can use the SMS Message Detail Report that gives you more or less all the detail you could ever need from MobileConnect. It contains a ClientID column and you could automate running the report from Analytics Builder as a CSV and import to a Data Extension using Automation Studio.