# Is there a System View for Mobile Connect Contacts / Subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sql, mobileconnect

For Email All Subscribers, we have _Subscribers data [view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) and I am looking for similar data view for All Mobile Connect Contacts. Basically, i would like to access all mobile numbers with their corresponding subscriber key / contact key.

I did notice _SubscriberSMS data [view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribersms.htm&type=5), but it doesn't support Mobile Connect. So not sure what this view does.

Answer (score 1):

the information you need is in _MobileAddress:
Fields _MobileNumber and _ContactID.

You can find more information in this answered question:
[Accessing _MobileAddress and _MobileSubscription Data Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions)

Regards,
Cristina

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from _SMSSubscriptionLog data view. There you can find both required fields and it does work on mobile connect.

For more details, explore https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5