# MobileConnect data views

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect, sms

Where can I view the names of the data sets and their contents like; 
`_MobileAddress`, `_UndeliverableSms` & `_MobileSubscription`

i know there are others that might contain columns of information i need to query but they do not appear to be easy to find within Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There [**are details**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36326/5202) about `_MobileAddress` and `_Mobile Subscription` floating around SFSE.

I did find some info on `_UndeliverableSMS` [**here**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_retrieving_information_on_undelivered_sms_messages_for_mobileconnect.htm&type=5).

- MobileNumber, phone
- Undeliverable, boolean
- BounceCount, number
- FirstBounceDate, date
- HoldDate, date

None of these are officially documented on the [**Data Views**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) page, which is sad.