# What does the Status column specify in the MobileConnect Demographics and MobilePush Demographics

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush

What does the Status column specify in the MobileConnect Demographics and MobilePush Demographics? I want to build a custom preference management for SMS and Push and for that if some one opts out I want to update the status attribute of the Demographics tables accordingly. How are these tables accessible? Are the "_MobileAddress" and "_PushAddress" data extensions that are accessible via Ampscript/SQL same as the demographics table?

Answer (score 5):

**_MobileAddress._Status**

- 1 = active
- -1 = unspecified
- 2 = bounced
- 3 = held
- 4 = unsubscribed

**_MobileSubscription._OptOutStatusID**

- 0 = opted-in
- 1 = opted-out

**_MobileSubscription._OptInStatusID**

- 0 = opted-out
- 1 =  Opt-In Pending
- 2 = opted-in

Yes _MobileAddress and _PushAddress data views are available via SQL queries

There is API available to update the mobile connect subscription status.
Refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm)  You need to send a MO message to you shortcode or long code with the message parameter containing the stop keyword. This will then update the _MobileSubscription data view status columns

There might be similar API for mobile push unsubscribe as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I found the following Ampscript is actually updating : UpdateData('_MobileAddress',1,'_MobileNumber', '91xxxxxxxxxx','_Status',0). Also, what does the status column signify in Mobile Address when we have separate _OptInStatusID/_OptOutStatusID attributes in mobile subscription. Is it some sort of global/master/account level subscription status?

Comment: Also, are these officially documented anywhere?

Comment: @androemedaandroemeda, the _OptInStatusID/_OptOutStatusID attributes at Mobile subscription provides you the opt in and opt out status for each keyword of a long code or short code and the status column in Mobile Address seems to be more like global/master/account-level subscription status. MobileConnect changes the status of a mobile number to held when two messages bounce more than 30 days apart with no successful message delivery in between.

Comment: @androemedaandroemeda No, I didn't find any official documentation for this. I found some of this information from this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions

Comment: Hey @androemedaandroemeda - hope you were able to achieve the mobileconnect unsubscribe. I have the same requirement and when I use the AMPScript - UpdateData('_MobileAddress',1,'_MobileNumber', '91xxxxxxxxxx','_Status',4), the Subscriber status in my mobile demographics shows as 4. I had expected it to show as the word "Unsubscribed". Does it happen for you as well ? Is the contact actually unsubscribed with the 4 value?

Comment: Hi @Vic, yes for me also it shows 4 instead of 'Unsubscribed'. But whether the contact is actually unsubscribed is not documented anywhere

Comment: @androemedaandroemeda same here, you found any concrete answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about status, refer to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5.  The opt status values are applicable for both SMS and Push:

**OptInStatusID Key**

- NotOptedIn = 0
- OptInPending = 1
- OptedIn = 2
- DeletingNotOptedIn = 10
- DeletingOptInPending = 11
- DeletingOptedIn = 12