# SFMC - Querying All Contacts with SQL Query Activity (System Data Views)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, data-views

I am trying to create a data extension that contains all contacts from my enterprise account. I need a complete list of contacts as we are billed by SFMC per contact. Querying the data view _subscribers provides me with 90% of the contacts I need.

I have been advised by SFMC support that in addition to the population included in the _subscribers data view, other tables make up the "All Contacts" list. What they have not been able to provide me is the names of these data views and which columns they contain.

Here is an example of the system data views I am looking for:
[Accessing _MobileAddress and _MobileSubscription Data Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions)

I'm asking if someone would be so kind to provide me a list of these system data view along with the fields they contain so I can query them and build my All Contacts data extension.

Thank you

Z

Comment: This is no such data view that can give you your All Contacts. _Subscribers will give you only those subscribers that you have sent to in 6 months.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way for you to query certain system tables that would get you the full list of all billable contacts in your Marketing Cloud account.

There used to be an option to request Marketing Cloud support to enable a data view for All Contacts in the past, but due to performance issues Salesforce decided to disable it for everyone (including the ones that had it enabled).

However, Salesforce Data Architects *still* have a way to query it (or a combination of various backend tables) to get you an automation that fills up a Data Extension on a 24h basis with all contacts on your Marketing Cloud account.

The bad news? It requires contacting your Marketing Cloud Executive and requesting the assistance of Salesforce Service Team, which will cost a pretty penny. For reference, with my last client who had Email/Mobile/Push channels, MC Connect with Sales Cloud and manual Lead list uploads, there was no other way to get those Contacts to one Data Extension .. and SF guys asked for a number in five digits for setting up this automation.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the well thought out response. +1

Comment: Just for reference, the official article > https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000248054&type=1

Comment: Thanks for your frank answer. This is just one of the things that makes me which I could go back in time and argue against switching our marketing platform to SFMC.