# Is SubscriberKey the only field you can query from a MobileConnect list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, list, sql, mobileconnect

I need to query a MobileConnect List to delete some Contact records. I created a MobileConnect List and then used automation studio to query it into a DE.  This worked fine BUT is SubscriberKey the only field I can query?  My list has other fields (channel, source, Email Address, etc), but I can't seem to figure out how I can query them. And...once I can get that working, I also need someone to tell me how to query a list field I see as "Email Address"....how to account for the space?

(I am asking because I want to save a copy of the DE, in a non-sendable DE, before I run the delete - i'd like to have more info in that copy than just the subscriber key)

works fine:

select SubscriberKey
from [MyListName]

here are some examples of what I tried (none work):

select SubscriberKey, channel
from [MyListName]

select SubscriberKey, x.channel
from [MyListName] x

Answer (score 1):

If you do a [retrieve call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_dataextension_object.htm) on this object(DE) you will get the fields that are queryable.

But the only useful one is `Subscriberkey` it appears all the other fields have the same values for the entire audience

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the fields that you specify by querying Mobile Lists. Somehow, MC only lets you retrieve SubscriberKey from Mobile Lists both for MobileConnect and MobilePush.

You can use MobileConnect data views to retrieve all the fields available on MobileConnect Data. Please check [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36326/78225) to see available fields and data views. From these data view, you can also query any custom field that you have on that data view.