# What is the most accurate place to pull MobileConnect metrics?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I've been looking through Report Builder for MobileConnect reports, and I've also pulled the SMS DataViews. I'm also referencing the MobileConnect UI, and it seems none of the numbers are lining up with one another.
I'm looking to do a basic report of people who are subscribed, opt-outs, delivered/undelivered, inbound/outbound messages, keyword metrics.

Which method is the most accurate way to pull MobileConnect metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace yourself, this won't be easy...

For subscriber data access [_MobileAddress and _MobileSubscription` Data Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions), but be aware that:

- multiple contacts can have the same phone number assigned
- one person can have multiple phones associated, but their newest one has 1 in the Priority field
- keyword-level opt-ins are not the only thing you need to track, there's a `Status` field in `_MobileAddress` - if the value there is `Inactive` no SMS is sent (if I remember correctly this is set when somebody sends a STOP message, but my memory is hazy on this one)

For SMS messages, use the [_SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view, but know that:

- if a text message consisted of many parts (was concatenated), they will be in a random order here which you need to stitch back together to get the full message
- as with most data views, you won't be able to retrieve the full send history

There's also the [Undeliverable SMS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_undeliverable_sms.htm&type=5) data view which tells you the count of mobile bounces of a phone number.