# Inherit contact mobile number of Parent Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, sfmc-business-unit

When looking to All Contacts list in child BU, I can't see mobile number inherited, its only email address.

Can it inherit contacts mobile number (not just email address) from Parent Business Unit into Child Business Unit in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no - Mobile Connect data tables on different business units are separate from each other by default.

You could extract them using the [_MobileAddress and _MobileSubscription](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions) system tables and import the contacts to child business units, but you would to be extra careful to keep the opt-ins synchronized between all business units that contain the same customer.